# How to change the value of a service variable from the component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my code, the user input should get passed to the deviceName string in my component (which it does), which in turn should get passed to the deviceIP string in my service.

I'm guessing the order in which I used the get / set methods is incorrect. Can anyone help me figure out what I've done wrong?

Here's my component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-section-computer-management',
templateUrl: './section-computer-management.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./section-computer-management.component.css'],
})

export class SectionComputerManagementComponent implements OnInit {
ping: number = 0;
public deviceName = 'cstorch-3420';

constructor(private _pingService: PingService) {
this._pingService.pingStream.subscribe(ping => {
  this.ping = ping; });
}

changeDIP(val){
  this._pingService.setDIP(this.deviceName);
}

showDIV() {
  alert(`GV ${this._pingService.getDIP}`);
}



ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Here's my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class PingService {
pingStream: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
ping: number = 0;


deviceIp = "";
url = `http://${this.deviceIp}`;

setDIP(val: string) {
this.deviceIp = val;
}
getDIP(val: string) {
return this.deviceIp;
}

constructor(private _http: Http) {
interval(1000)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    let timeStart: number = performance.now();

    this._http.get(this.url)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        let timeEnd: number = performance.now();

        let ping: number = timeEnd - timeStart;
        this.ping = ping;
        this.pingStream.next(ping);
      });
  });
}
}
```

Here's the template I'm using

```
 <div class="section-container">
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card text mb-3 shadow card-theme">
                <div class="card-header card-header-theme text-center">
                    <h5>Please Enter A Device Name or IP Address</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div ng-app="">
                        <p align="center"><input class ='form-control input-lg' 
    style= "width:300px" [(ngModel)]="deviceName" type="text"> {{deviceName}} 
    </p> 

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-center mb-3 shadow card-theme">
                <div class="card-header card-header-theme">
                    <h5>Machine Ping</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                        {{ping | number:'1.0-0'}}ms
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row-fluid cards">
                <div class="card shadow card-theme">
                    <div class="card-body">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="card shadow card-theme">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go 
somewhere</a>
                              </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and finally the module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { SectionDashboardComponent } from './Sections/section-dashboard/section-dashboard.component';
import { SectionComputerManagementComponent } from './Sections/section-computer-management/section-computer-management.component';
import { SectionHelpdeskLinksComponent } from './Sections/section-helpdesk-links/section-helpdesk-links.component';
import { BarChartComponent } from './charts/bar-chart/bar-chart.component';
import { LineChartComponent } from './charts/line-chart/line-chart.component';
import { PieChartComponent } from './charts/pie-chart/pie-chart.component';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { freshServiceService } from './Services/freshservice.service';
import { PingService } from './Services/pingservice.service';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    SectionDashboardComponent,
    SectionComputerManagementComponent,
    SectionHelpdeskLinksComponent,
    BarChartComponent,
    LineChartComponent,
    PieChartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ChartsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,


  ],
  providers: [freshServiceService, PingService, HttpClient],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at your template

Comment: Share your module.ts also, or the module where you imported your components and service.

Comment: why does your `getDIP(val: string) {
return this.deviceIp;
}` takes a parameter?

Comment: @nircraft  because I thought that was how I passed my variable through to the getDIP function from the component. I must be way off.

Comment: use a getter and setter from typescript

Comment: Side note, the ping function does work and displays to the template from the service, but the user input to enter the name doesn't get pushed to the service, even when I pre-set the value to a random machine name.

Answer (score 1):

The `setDIP` method is defined in your component but it is never called. You are not calling this method when you write something into input field. You need to catch a `change` event on input field and execute the `setDIP` method.

Change your code like this:

```
<p align="center"><input class ='form-control input-lg' 
    style= "width:300px" [(ngModel)]="deviceName" (change)="setDIP($event.target.value)" type="text"> {{deviceName}} 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using getter and setter from typescript:

in MyService.ts

```
_ping: number = 0;

public set ping(ping: number) {
  this._ping = ping;
}

public get ping() {
  return this._ping;
}
```

in component.ts

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {}

changePing() {
  this.service.ping = 1;
  console.log(this.service.ping);
  // 1
}
```